# docker run and build from github to a local vm?

Tags: linux, docker, github

can i know is there any possibility to run docker build from my local Linux getting the files from GitHub and run the image after build in my local virtual machine?

which means there will be no physical files from my repository in my local Linux but only letting GitHub to do all the builds and i get the image from GitHub to run in my local virtual machine instead. is this possible?

As far as i know, Docker repository linking with GitHub is no longer available for free tier account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question well, you can use [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) to build your Docker image and push it to the [GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry).  Then, you can pull that Docker image from GitHub Packages and run it on your local machine.

Comment: More broadly, you can set up any continuous-integration system to push to any repository (use Jenkins to push to Docker Hub; use GitLab to push to AWS ECR; ...) to run the image inside the VM without rebuilding it.